# Accordion menu expand - menu change

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the vertical accordion menu, i want to replace the menu content with other menu or a division. This is my code

```
<nav>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
           <div> New Menu 1</div> 
      <ul>
        After clicking on each header we will show/hide the internal navigation links. This situation can get tricky when trying to implement sub-navigation and sub-sub-navigation if you want to show/hide those as well. A better solution is to nest a third  element which is also displayed immediately with all the other links, but rendered using additional padding.


      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
         <div> New Menu 2</div>
      <ul>
        Create html drop down menus for web page navigation in a few clicks! Define text, font, color, URL and more for the multilevel dropdown menus. You don't need to write any code by yourself. Horizontal drop down menus builder will generate it for you. You can preview menus in web browser without quitting the program. Css drop down menus render perfectly in Firefox, Safari and Chrome. Html drop down menus also works on non-CSS3 compitable browsers
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
         <div> New Menu 3</div>
      <ul>
        PURE CSS Menu Maker is a free and powerful graphical user interface for creating 100% pure CSS web menus. CSS menus do not require JavaScript or plug-ins in order to run. PURE CSS Menu Maker can create horizontal as well as vertical menus. Menus generated with PURE CSS Menu Maker may be modified freely, either with PURE CSS Menu Maker or by hand.
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

script

```
 $(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#nav > li > ul:eq(0)').show();
  $("#nav > li > a").on("click", function(e)
  {
    if($(this).parent().has("ul")) 
    {

        e.preventDefault();
    }

    if(!$(this).hasClass("open")) 
    {
      // hide any open menus and remove all other classes
      $("#nav li ul").slideUp(350);

      $("#nav li a").removeClass("open");


      // open our new menu and add the open class
      $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);

      $(this).addClass("open");

    }

    else if($(this).hasClass("open")) {
      $(this).removeClass("open");
      $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
    }
  });
});
```

On click i want to change the menu with div and hide that div on next menu click. How it can done? Thanks.

here is a fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/sW96K/

Comment: Can you simulate the same on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: and check you markup, this is not so good :
<ul>
        PURE CSS Menu Maker is a free and powerful graphical user interface for creating 100% pure CSS web menus. CSS menus do not require JavaScript or plug-ins in order to run. PURE CSS Menu Maker can create horizontal as well as vertical menus. Menus generated with PURE CSS Menu Maker may be modified freely, either with PURE CSS Menu Maker or by hand.
      </ul>

Answer (score 0):

You can try using simple `slideToggle()`

```
           $(document).ready(function()
              {
                  $('#nav > li > ul:eq(0)').show();
                  $("#nav li a").on("click", function(e)
                     {
                         $(this).siblings("ul").slideToggle(350);
                     });
              });
```

check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Kritika/ZXE6K/

this code will open one menu onclick but it wont close other open menus. this is simple hide/show
div

Comment: When I can change the menu..?

Comment: @Aneesh: what menu you want to change?

Comment: Means, when i click Menu 1, i want to change the contents of that menu with a new division ( <div> New Menu 1</div> ).

Answer (score 0):

You want like this? Small scripts can handle this. DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/HmwN8/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.toggle').on('click', function(){
        $('.content').slideUp('2000', "easeOutBounce");

        if($('div#'+$(this).attr('rel')).css('display')=='block')
            $('div#'+$(this).attr('rel')).slideUp('2000', "easeOutBounce");
        else
            $('div#'+$(this).attr('rel')).slideDown('2000', "easeOutBounce");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess i understand what you meant now.. It should be something like this:

edit: its simple re-instantiate with a function each time u replace the content..

```
function doit(element) {
    $(element).on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newElement = $(element).next();
        $(element).parent().siblings().each(function(){
            if(!$(this).children('a').is(':visible')){
                $(this).children('div').clone().hide().insertAfter($(this).children('a'));
                $(this).children('div:first-child').replaceWith($(this).children('a').show());
                $(this).children('ul').hide(350);
                doit($(this).children('a'));
            }
        });
        $(element).clone().hide().insertAfter($(element).next());
        $(element).replaceWith($(element).next().show());
        $(newElement).next().next().slideToggle(350); // slide toggle in 350ms
        doit(newElement);
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav > li > ul').hide(); // Hide all menus
    $('#nav > li > div').hide(); // Hide all divs under menus
    $("#nav > li > a").each(function() {
        doit(this);
    });
    $('#nav > li:first-child > a').click(); // Open first element
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/evxPq/

Comment: its fine, but when i click the menu 1 again or click to any other button, i want to replace the new manu with previous menu.

Comment: well it is working but what you expect to happen is not happening i guess.. and you keep failing to tell what you really want. Sorry but i cant help you this way.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#default
In this, on click of section1, i want to replace the contents in section1 with a division.
Then i click another section, section 1 will changed to previous state( means previous menu) and the new clicked section data replaced with another division. Expansion needed for each section clicks.

Comment: Hi, some correction in my comment.
My requirement is: From the code posted by me at the top- the accordion menu works fine. When i click the Menu 1, next ul content expanded. In this case, when i click menu 1- i want to expand the ul content and also replace the menu 1 with div content.
Hope you can understand it now.

Comment: @ Berker Yüceer Hope u can understand..?

Comment: Hi, can u understand this.?

Comment: Hi, thanks. it works fine. But i need a small change. In default (onload) i want to expand the menu 1 content. 
And when clicks any other menus - expand corresponding content and, need to collapse all other menu content.

Comment: @Aneesh its really simple u just need to reinstantiate the function for all other siblings.. check again.

Comment: Hi, i have a change on this. When i click menu, want to hide the menu and slide down the content. Then clicks next menu, hide the first menu content,show the menu 1 and slide down the content of menu 2. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

see the following link.Youo can find different types of Accordionz

```
http://jqueryui.com/accordion/
```